# Can't connect cifs share : 128 key has been revoked

Tags: mount, kerberos, cifs, key

Since 1 month, i can't connect to my DFS share from any Linux server.

```
[root@server /]#  mount -t cifs //server/share/saves /mnt -o username=user,domain=domain.com
Password for user@//server/share/saves :  ****************
mount error(128): Key has been revoked
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

What should i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found. running command dmesg :

```
[480378.875310] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\server\share
[480378.879835] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000072 STATUS_ACCOUNT_DISABLED
[480378.879862] CIFS: VFS: \\server Send error in SessSetup = -128
[480378.880182] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -128
```

Account was disabled... reactivated and it is working.